# Fill text effect on hover of span

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the colour of a link on hover by gradually filling it from left to right. However, it doesn't seem to be working, it just fills the text immediately?

I'm trying to get it so when someone hovers over the `li`, the fill begins for the `span`

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.navbar_wrapper-li {
  display: block;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  user-select: none;
}

span {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navbar_wrapper-li:hover span:before {
  width: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(data-text);
  transition: all 0.9s;
}

.navbar_wrapper-li:hover span:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar_wrapper-ul">
  <li class="navbar_wrapper-li">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">
      <span data-text="Home">Home</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You just `hover` on span instead of li and span both, because hover on li and span are conflicting

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.navbar_wrapper-li {
  display: block;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  user-select: none;
}

span {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: block;
}

.navbar_wrapper-li span:before {
  width: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(data-text);
  transition: all 0.9s;
}

.navbar_wrapper-li span:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar_wrapper-ul">
  <li class="navbar_wrapper-li">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">
      <span data-text="Home">Home</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to consider background coloration using gradient but you will have [less support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip#Browser_compatibility):

```css
.box {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(grey,grey) left no-repeat,
    #fff;
  background-size:0% 100%;
  font-size:40px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.box:hover {
  background-size:100% 100%;
}

body {
 padding:50px 0;
 text-align:center;
 background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Home
</div>
```